# Add the value of multiple sliders in swift then average them?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Im doing this wrong I but I'm not sure how to get it I could really use some help. I have 3 sliders (I may need more later) and basically they are 1-10 in value kinda for a rating system and i want them averaged to create an average score.. so this is what I have

```
@IBOutlet weak var speed: UISlider!
@IBAction func speedChange(sender: AnyObject) {
let speedValue = speed.value
}


@IBOutlet weak var body: UISlider!
@IBAction func bodyChange(sender: AnyObject) {
let bodyValue = body.value
}


@IBOutlet weak var details: UISlider!
@IBAction func detailsChange(sender: AnyObject) {
let detailsValue = details.value
}


@IBOutlet weak var score: UILabel!

func final() {

var thescore = (speed.value + body.value + details.value) / 3    
score.text = "\(thescore)"

}
```

Only problem is it doesn't work. the + errors out, so I need to fix that, but even still i think my methodology is completely off.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. Are you sure the outlets in the storyboard are linked to your Controller ?
Also, you may want to call your function final every time a slider changed its value, like this :

```
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderA: UISlider!
    @IBAction func sliderAchanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        fonction()
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var sliderB: UISlider!
    @IBAction func sliderBchanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        fonction()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var sliderC: UISlider!
    @IBAction func sliderCchanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        fonction()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        fonction()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func fonction() {
        var thescore = (sliderA.value + sliderB.value + sliderC.value ) / 3
        label.text = "\(thescore)"
    }​
```

And I added a call to the function in viewDidLoad method to initilaize the label's text.